# JPanel Drawing Glitch

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am using a JPanel to draw my game onto, using a fixed game loop, and double buffering; however I get a glitch somewhere on the screen. The glitch is a screen tearing visual artifact that stretches across X axis, and is about 20 pixels tall.

I have recreated the problem in 1 class, as shown below. To recreate the problem, you can run the code and move the square around with the arrow keys, when the square moves over the place where the visual tearing occurs, you should see the effect. (The location of the visual tearing seems to be random)

I recreated a single frame of what the image tearing looks like, however when running, it shows a flickering effect.

[image]

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Panel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Panel();
    }

    public Panel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game!");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface View {

        public BufferedImage switchBuffers();
        public int getWidth();
        public int getHeight();

    }

    public enum KeyState {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements View {

        private Engine engine;

        private BufferedImage active;
        private BufferedImage update;

        private ReentrantLock lckBuffer;

        public TestPane() {
            lckBuffer = new ReentrantLock();
            initBuffers();
            engine = new Engine(this);
            engine.gameStart();

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "up_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "down_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "left_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "right_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "up_released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "down_released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "left_released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "right_released");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("up_pressed", new AddState(engine, KeyState.UP));
            am.put("up_released", new RemoveState(engine, KeyState.UP));
            am.put("down_pressed", new AddState(engine, KeyState.DOWN));
            am.put("down_released", new RemoveState(engine, KeyState.DOWN));
            am.put("left_pressed", new AddState(engine, KeyState.LEFT));
            am.put("left_released", new RemoveState(engine, KeyState.LEFT));
            am.put("right_pressed", new AddState(engine, KeyState.RIGHT));
            am.put("right_released", new RemoveState(engine, KeyState.RIGHT));
        }

        protected void initBuffers() {
            if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0) {
                try {
                    lckBuffer.lock();
                    active = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    update = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                } finally {
                    lckBuffer.unlock();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            initBuffers();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 800);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            try {
                lckBuffer.lock();
                if (active != null) {
                    g2d.drawImage(active, 0, 0, this);
                }
            } finally {
                lckBuffer.unlock();
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public BufferedImage switchBuffers() {
            try {
                lckBuffer.lock();
                BufferedImage tmp = active;
                active = update;
                update = tmp;
                repaint();
            } finally {
                lckBuffer.unlock();
            }
            return update;
        }

    }

    public static class Engine {

        public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 15 * 4;
        public static final int MAP_HEIGHT = 9 * 4;
        public static final int X_DELTA = 8;
        public static final int Y_DELTA = 8;

        //This value would probably be stored elsewhere.
        public static final double GAME_HERTZ = 60.0;
        //Calculate how many ns each frame should take for our target game hertz.
        public static final double TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000000000 / GAME_HERTZ;
        //We will need the last update time.
        static double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
        //Store the last time we rendered.
        static double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

        //If we are able to get as high as this FPS, don't render again.
        final static double TARGET_FPS = GAME_HERTZ;
        final static double TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;

        //Simple way of finding FPS.
        static int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

        public static int fps = 60;
        public static int frameCount = 0;

        public int x, y;

        private boolean isGameFinished;

        private View view;

        private Set<KeyState> keyStates;

        public Engine(View bufferRenderer) {
            keyStates = new HashSet<>(4);
            this.view = bufferRenderer;
        }

        public void gameStart() {

            x = (800/2) - (60/2);
            y = (800/2) - (60/2);
            Thread gameThread = new Thread() {
                // Override run() to provide the running behavior of this thread.
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gameLoop();
                }
            };
            gameThread.setDaemon(false);
            // Start the thread. start() calls run(), which in turn calls gameLoop().
            gameThread.start();
        }

        public void gameLoop() {
            BufferedImage buffer = view.switchBuffers(); // initial buffer...
            while (!isGameFinished) {
                double now = System.nanoTime();
                lastUpdateTime += TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                gameUpdate(buffer);
                renderBuffer(buffer);
                buffer = view.switchBuffers(); // Push the buffer back
                frameCount++;
                lastRenderTime = now;
                int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);
                if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime) {
                    fps = frameCount;
                    frameCount = 0;
                    lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
                }
                while (now - lastRenderTime < TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS && now - lastUpdateTime < TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) {
                    Thread.yield();
                    try { Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    now = System.nanoTime();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void renderBuffer(BufferedImage buffer) {
            if (buffer != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, buffer.getWidth(), buffer.getHeight());
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2d.fillRect(x, y, 60, 60);
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2d.drawString("FPS: "+Engine.fps, 0, 10);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        protected void gameUpdate(BufferedImage buffer) {

            if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.DOWN)) {
                y = y + Y_DELTA;
            } else if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.UP)) {
                y = y - Y_DELTA;
            }
            if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.RIGHT)) {
                x = x + X_DELTA;
            } else if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.LEFT)) {
                x = x - X_DELTA;
            }
        }

        public void addKeyState(KeyState state) {
            keyStates.add(state);
        }

        public void removeKeyState(KeyState state) {
            keyStates.remove(state);
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class AddState extends AbstractAction {

        private Engine engine;
        private KeyState state;

        public AddState(Engine engine, KeyState state) {
            this.engine = engine;
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            engine.addKeyState(state);
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class RemoveState extends AbstractAction {

        private Engine engine;
        private KeyState state;

        public RemoveState(Engine engine, KeyState state) {
            this.engine = engine;
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            engine.removeKeyState(state);
        }

    }

}
```

Edit: There is a small chance that the screen tearing doesn't occur, (I believe this is because the frames are in sync with the screen)

Edit2: Some people have told me that this problem doesn't occur on their hardware, how could I fix this problem for my hardware?

Comment: I believe your code to lock the graphics buffer is causing problems.  You should not use a lock on the SwingThread, rather it should query data provider threads for info then draw whatever is required.

Comment: Well I moved the darn white square all over the place and couldn't reproduce this

Comment: This is, as was suggested in the [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419808/frames-painting-at-different-times), likely a hardware issue..

Comment: Have you tried reducing the frame rate?

Comment: How would I fix the problem given my hardware then? Like I mentioned in the original post, my set up should be more than capable of running this..

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't think a hardware issue should be considered until the locks are eliminated.  And why would the issue only happen with this Java code?

Comment: I just tried reducing the frame rate now. No effect.

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Comment: @user417896 Embedded graphics cards are well known for been...less then optimised.  Given that it runs on two of my PCs and two of Macs with issue...do you have a better solution...

Comment: I am using jdk1.7.0_67

Comment: @MadProgrammer Remove the locks!

Comment: @RyanRamsden You still haven't told me what graphics card you're using (or what OS, but I think you're running Windows).  In this case, the graphics card would be your bottle neck.  I can run this example of a PC that is 5+ years old with 8gig of RAM with no issues...

Comment: @user417896 The code provided on this question was given to me by MadProgrammer from the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419808/frames-painting-at-different-times), I have shown my other methods of attempting this there, so far, none have fixed the problem.

Comment: @user417896 Why?  They aren't doing anything OTHER then ensuring that the `BufferedImage` is complete.  If they were `synchronised` blocks I would agree, but `Lock` is far more efficient...besides, have you tried and have you seen a difference?  If you go to the original question, you will see we attempt three different solutions, with no success, the issue has to come down to hardware.  In three attempts, I was unable to replicate the issues been faced by Ryan.  Either it's the video card, video drivers or screen or a combination of two or more...

Comment: @RyanRamsden did you try what I am saying?  I bet it will work.  The code provided is not very good multi-threading wise.  Never seen a professional example that looks like that...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did send you my graphics card last time. [here](http://www.kfa2.com/gtx570.shtml), but like I said, I don't know if i's embedded or not, and yes, I am using Windows 7 64bit

Comment: @RyanRamsden Well, that should be more the capable...

Comment: @user417896 I will put it bluntly, I don't know how to; like I said, the code was given to me by MadProgrammer, I was planning on studying it when I got it to work properly. I tried the naive approach of removing the `lckBuffer.lock();'` and 'lckBuffer.unlock();`, but that just caused the screen to flash.

Comment: @RyanRamsden Can I ask, have you tried this on other PCs (and not just this example, but the other three as well?)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't have access to any other computers, so no.

Comment: @RyanRamsden It has some strange loops like the repaint() call within the lock.  I would start from scratch keeping it simple and testing each piece as you make progress.  Look at examples online.

Comment: The `thread.sleep(1)` scares me...

Comment: @RyanRamsden You need to understand what each and every piece does, moreover be mindful of what thread it is running on.

Comment: Without the locks - 0 millisecond update, with the locks 1 millisecond update per cycle...

Comment: @user417896 I understand that, and I have no intention of having any code in my project that I don't understand, however I don't see the point in learning code that doesn't give me the intended result, that's why I'm asking for help first, and then I can review it afterwards..

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've tried it with and without the `thread.sleep(1)` and it didn't change anything..

Comment: @RyanRamsden The problem is, you really should be using `Thread.sleep(duration)` instead, where the direction is the "optimal time between paint cycles" - "the amount of time it took to do the last paint cycle".  Currently, it probably takes more time to schedule the sleep then it takes to actually perform it

Comment: We learn by trying and practice, examples guide us but when we don't understand what is going on in them these kinds of errors creep up.  @MadProgrammer Its never justifiable to use sleep() to fix errors.  It implies a serious fault in the multi-threading code.

Comment: @user417896 1- I didn't write the loop code; 2- It scares me; 3- The inclusion of `Thread.sleep` here is designed, in this case, to ensure an even distribution of time between the update cycles, in this, 60 fps.  This is pretty much how all games/animation work...

Comment: @RyanRamsden Have you tried another example from a Java based game engine?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I haven't really, I just tried a bunch of different ones, however they all use JPanels, and I believe that's the problem. I have seen other ones which use DataBufferInts, however I have no experience with this, and It would require redoing a lot of my code, and I'm already getting to the point of admitting defeat and giving up.. I've spent almost 1 week straight on this 1 problem.

Comment: @RyanRamsden Look for a game engine that uses `Canvas`, this is the closest you can get to the hardware from within Java, without have JNI involved...

Comment: I thought i'd just add, I used [this](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0) tutorial for the game loop.

Comment: @RyanRamsden [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) comes up a lot here, you could have a look [at this discussion](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/651239-best-game-engine-for-java/) as well...

Comment: @RyanRamsden Have you tried running any of those examples from the "game loop" tutorial?  I'd be interested in knowing how they work for you...

Comment: I would strongly recommend switching to use Canvas in Swing.

Comment: There is really little need to use a sleep function for that purpose.  Just let the pc update as much as it can.  You do the number crunching in separate threads.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't really want to use any external libraries, and there must be a way to fix my problem without going to them.

Comment: @user417896 Would switching to Canvas fix my problem? And the problem still remains even if I remove the sleep function.

Comment: I have not tried it with your code, but all of my code uses canvas. The graphics loop checks for info to draw that is generated by another thread running the game loop.

Comment: I would recommend you research multi-threading with swing, you will be a much better programmer for it.

Comment: @RyanRamsden I demonstrated the use of `Canvas` with the `BufferStrategy`, which you said didn't help...

Comment: Its a threading issue... good luck guys

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah, yes, sorry. You did demonstrate the use of Canvas with BufferStrategies and VolatileImages.

Comment: @user417896 If it's a threading issue, what is wrong with the current set up?

Comment: @RyanRamsden Personally, I don't think it's a threading issue as the `Canvas` solution basically throws that out the window (piping the update directly to the hardware).  One thing you might try (for ALL the examples) is adding `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();` after you've updated the screen buffer...

Comment: @RyanRamsden Even though you don't want to use a third party library, it might be worth while downloading them and check out their examples and seeing if they have the same (or similar) problems

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS A TEST - NOT A ANSWER**

This is the most simplistic Swing based example I can come up with.  I paints directly to the `JPanel` and will try and update every 16 milliseconds (60fps)

I would suggest that you play with the `X_DELTA` and `Y_DELTA` values as well as commenting out `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();` in and out to see if it makes a difference...

nb- Both examples use a "direct" painting process.  That is, rather the using a `BufferedImage` (or other backing buffer), they paint directly to the `Graphics` context

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BasicAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BasicAnimation();
    }

    public BasicAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum KeyState {

        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Set<KeyState> keyStates;

        private Point player = new Point(200, 200);

        public static final int X_DELTA = 4;
        public static final int Y_DELTA = 4;

        public TestPane() {
            keyStates = new HashSet<>(4);
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "up_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "down_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "left_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "right_pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "up_released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "down_released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "left_released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "right_released");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("up_pressed", new AddState(KeyState.UP));
            am.put("up_released", new RemoveState(KeyState.UP));
            am.put("down_pressed", new AddState(KeyState.DOWN));
            am.put("down_released", new RemoveState(KeyState.DOWN));
            am.put("left_pressed", new AddState(KeyState.LEFT));
            am.put("left_released", new RemoveState(KeyState.LEFT));
            am.put("right_pressed", new AddState(KeyState.RIGHT));
            am.put("right_released", new RemoveState(KeyState.RIGHT));

            Timer timer = new Timer(16, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    updateState();
                    repaint();
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void updateState() {

            if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.UP)) {
                player.y -= Y_DELTA;
            } else if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.DOWN)) {
                player.y += Y_DELTA;
            }

            if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.LEFT)) {
                player.x -= X_DELTA;
            } else if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.RIGHT)) {
                player.x += X_DELTA;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(player.x - 25, player.y - 25, 50, 50);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void addKeyState(KeyState state) {
            keyStates.add(state);
        }

        public void removeKeyState(KeyState state) {
            keyStates.remove(state);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        public class AddState extends AbstractAction {

            private final KeyState state;

            public AddState(KeyState state) {
                this.state = state;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addKeyState(state);
            }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        public class RemoveState extends AbstractAction {

            private final KeyState state;

            public RemoveState(KeyState state) {
                this.state = state;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                removeKeyState(state);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Included a `Canvas`/`BufferStrategy` example as well.  Some deal, play with the `X/Y_Delta` values and enable/disable `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BasicAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BasicAnimation();
    }

    public BasicAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GameView());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum KeyState {

        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public static class GameView extends Canvas {

        private Set<KeyState> keyStates;

        private Point player = new Point(200, 200);

        public static final int X_DELTA = 4;
        public static final int Y_DELTA = 4;

        private GameThread gt;

        public GameView() {
            keyStates = new HashSet<>(4);
            gt = new GameThread(this);

            setFocusable(true);

            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                            addKeyState(KeyState.UP);
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                            addKeyState(KeyState.DOWN);
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                            addKeyState(KeyState.LEFT);
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                            addKeyState(KeyState.RIGHT);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                            removeKeyState(KeyState.UP);
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                            removeKeyState(KeyState.DOWN);
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                            removeKeyState(KeyState.LEFT);
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                            removeKeyState(KeyState.RIGHT);
                            break;
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            gt.start();
            requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            gt.stop();
            super.removeNotify();
        }

        public void updateState() {

            if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.UP)) {
                player.y -= Y_DELTA;
            } else if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.DOWN)) {
                player.y += Y_DELTA;
            }

            if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.LEFT)) {
                player.x -= X_DELTA;
            } else if (keyStates.contains(KeyState.RIGHT)) {
                player.x += X_DELTA;
            }

        }

        public void paintState(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(player.x - 25, player.y - 25, 50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        public void addKeyState(KeyState state) {
            keyStates.add(state);
        }

        public void removeKeyState(KeyState state) {
            keyStates.remove(state);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        public class AddState extends AbstractAction {

            private final KeyState state;

            public AddState(KeyState state) {
                this.state = state;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addKeyState(state);
            }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        public class RemoveState extends AbstractAction {

            private final KeyState state;

            public RemoveState(KeyState state) {
                this.state = state;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                removeKeyState(state);
            }

        }
    }

    public static class GameThread implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean keepRunning = true;
        private GameView view;
        private Thread currentThread;

        public GameThread(GameView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void start() {
            if (currentThread == null) {
                keepRunning = true;
                currentThread = new Thread(this);
                currentThread.start();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            keepRunning = false;
            if (currentThread != null) {
                try {
                    currentThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (keepRunning) {
                view.updateState();
                BufferStrategy bs = view.getBufferStrategy();
                do {
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
                    view.paintState(g2d);
                    g2d.dispose();
                } while (bs.contentsLost());
                bs.show();
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(16);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This removes most of the problems, however there is still a problem, about every second, the square produces a choppy visual artifact for a few frames. Commenting out the 'Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();' doesn't change this problem

Comment: Oh boy, this is fun.  Try adding `setIgnoreRepaint(true);` in the constructor of either example

Comment: Still no change after adding `setIgnoreRepaint(true);`

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  You're running on Windows right?  Are the video and DirectX drivers up-to-date ?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode), Yes I am using Windows, and my drivers are up to date.

Comment: @Ryan Ramsden there are a some issues on Win7/8 and specifics nVidia GPUs (epsecially laptops) , but is about Java version for compilator (last two months back was actual this issue), never faced, despite the fact that I'm have ..., I'm nVidia familair

Comment: @mKorbel I usually have issues with Radeon cards, ave nVidia in most of my Windows machines and not having any problems like this (Java 7 & 8)

Comment: @MadProgrammer there were issues with doublebuffering for JComponent, but is about compile-time libraries not about runtime, can't found discusion by camickr about this issue, I'm sure that has similair result as is here, in your ....

Comment: @mKorbel If you can find it, I'd love a read, because I'm at my witts end of things to suggest...

Comment: I have been looking around to see other alternatives, and how other examples work. I haven't looked at very many, however, [this](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#KineticModel) example uses JPanels, and when I run it, it does not give any visual artifacts. I'm currently trying to reduce the code so I can use it for myself, however, may be someone more experienced than me can find out what this code has, that mine doesn't; which makes it run properly.

Comment: @Ryan Ramsden (not mentioned here) 16milis is very expensive, touched latency of Native OS (to use 25/33/50), to translate this value to Mhz and to compare with max refresh frequency in the setting for your display, forgot about that your GPU/display is able to rendering 4k video, those mediaplayers has access to GPS and processes are optimized quite good, AWT/Swing is from last century, in this case NTSC/PAL was top (24/5frames per second)

Comment: @Ryan Ramsden in the [trashgods](http://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod) code example is used 25milis,

Comment: [here are topics about nVidia](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+nvidia) part of them are tagged by me, is easier to search for ..

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for the input, but I don't really know how I can use your information to help solve my problem..

Comment: @RyanRamsden I've had a (very quick) look of the Kinetic model example and they are not doing anything particularly special, it's a `javax.swing.Timer` and `paintComponent` essentially.  Have you tried upping the refresh rate (from 25 to 60) to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @Ryan Ramsden haven't any issue there, can't reproduce that, out of luck, and be sure that here is only a few gurus like as MadProgrammer that are willing to bother with :-), his answer is good and correct

Comment: @MadProgrammer yep, I increased the refresh rate to 60, and everything is still smooth.. It's a mystery to me too.

Comment: @RyanRamsden Just beware that the refresh rate (within the code) is max'ed to 60fps, you'll need to modify the state of the spinner's model to increase it.  I had up to 120 without issue...was kind of fun...

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `g2d.dipose()` from the `paintComponent(g)` method. To go inside the `try{}catch()` statement right after you draw the active image.

Comment: The `Graphics2D` context is created with `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();`, which means, if you remove the `dispose` call, you will be leaving resources in memory, which will eventually cause you to run out memory...I would argue the point that it's not necessary to have either though...

Comment: I have reviewed the code a little more and see that my suggestion wont do anything. Even if he had **MOVED** the g2d.dispose() from inside the paintComponent(g) method to inside of the try block statement near the g2d.drawImage() it would do the same thing.

Comment: You don't have this problem if you use Swing's Canvas. It provides a graphics buffer for you...

Comment: This looks like something caused because of double buffering.

Comment: @user417896 Actually, the last example I did for Ryan used `Canvas` and `BufferStrategy` which did not solve the problem...apparently, but I agree, it would my preferred method

Comment: I only know one way of doing a game loop, other than that it takes me like a day to figure out how the code works for someone else's game loop. The **FREAKING** nanoseconds and things like that make me frustrated because i only understand the basics of it. But... i'm still learning:)

Comment: @main_class Personally, nanoseconds are overkill, but that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The Canvas solution did fix the normal problem, but created a new one, which gave the rendering a 'choppy' feeling, even though it reported to be running at 60fps.

Comment: @RyanRamsden now that you switched to canvas, get rid of the sleep code.  Let the cpu update as fast as it can.

Comment: @user417896 It's hard to see if the problem persists, because by doing this, the update is called very many times, and the screen moves too fast to see if there is a problem.