# How to replicate a visual artifact bug

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a program that draws a square that I can drive around on a JPanel. I had this problem where whenever I would drive it, it would leave artifacts from where it had been on the screen. Kind of would look like [JPanel Drawing Glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496911/jpanel-drawing-glitch) when I would drive it around. Then I found a solution online that at the beginning of my paint(Graphics g) method, I should place a "super.paintComponent(g)".

That worked perfectly. But at the same time I kind of enjoyed have the opportunity to mess around with drawing with this car, so I added a piece of code that allowed me to choose whether or not I would be super.paintComponent(g)'ing. But when I transferred this code to another computer, it no longer had the original bug, not allowing me to paint if I wanted to. My question is: How can I replicate this bug, drawing all my previous positions behind me as I drive?

Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by chris on 1/5/16.
 */
public class Game extends JPanel{
int[] size = new int[2];
private Car car;
private JFrame frame;
private final double speedScalar = .5;
private final double angleScalar = 5;
boolean isTurningLeft = false;
boolean isTurningRight = false;
boolean isSpeedingUp = false;
boolean isSlowingDown = false;
private static Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
private ArrayList<Point> rocks = new ArrayList<>();
public static final int width = tk.getScreenSize().width;
public static final int height = tk.getScreenSize().height;
public boolean isDrawing = false;
public Color[] colorChoices = {Color.black,Color.blue,Color.red,Color.orange,Color.pink} ;
public Color chosenColor = Color.black;
public Game(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    car = new Car(300,300);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    frame.add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
                case 37:
                    isTurningLeft = true;
                    isTurningRight = false;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    isSpeedingUp = true;
                    isSlowingDown = false;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    isTurningLeft = false;
                    isTurningRight = true;
                    break;
                case 40:
                    isSpeedingUp = false;
                    isSlowingDown = true;
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
                case 37:
                    isTurningLeft = true;
                    isTurningRight = false;
                    break;
                case 40:
                    isSpeedingUp = true;
                    isSlowingDown = false;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    isTurningLeft = false;
                    isTurningRight = true;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    isSpeedingUp = false;
                    isSlowingDown = true;
                    break;
                case 32:
                    isDrawing = !isDrawing;

            }
            if(e.getKeyChar()=='c'){
                chosenColor = colorChoices[(int)(Math.random()*5)];
            } else if (e.getKeyChar()==' '){
                isDrawing=!isDrawing;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
                case 37:
                    isTurningLeft = false;
                    break;
                case 40:
                    isSpeedingUp = false;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    isTurningRight = false;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    isSlowingDown = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    Timer time = new Timer(1000/45, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(isTurningRight){
                car.setAngle(car.getAngle()+Math.toRadians(angleScalar));
            } else if (isTurningLeft){
                car.setAngle(car.getAngle()-Math.toRadians(angleScalar));
            }

            if(isSpeedingUp){
                car.setSpeed(car.getSpeed()-speedScalar);
            } else if (isSlowingDown){
                car.setSpeed(car.getSpeed()+speedScalar);
            }
            if(car.getSpeed()<0){
                car.setSpeed(0);
            }
            car.setX(car.getX() + (Math.cos(car.getAngle())*car.getSpeed()));
            car.setY(car.getY() + (Math.sin(car.getAngle())*car.getSpeed()));
            if(car.getX()<0){
                car.setX(0);
                car.setSpeed(0);
            }
            if(car.getX()>width){
                car.setX(width);
                car.setSpeed(0);
            }
            if(car.getY()<0){
                car.setY(0);
                car.setSpeed(0);
            }
            if(car.getY()>height){
                car.setY(height);
                car.setSpeed(0);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });
    double end = Math.random()*15;
    frame.setVisible(true);
    time.start();

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    if(!isDrawing) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    /**
     * Painting the car
     */
    g.setColor(chosenColor);
    double sin = Math.sin(car.getAngle());
    double cos = Math.cos(car.getAngle());
    int[] xPoints = {(int)car.getX(),(int)(car.getX()+cos*car.width),(int)(car.getX()-sin*car.length+cos*car.width),
            (int)(car.getX()-sin*car.length)};
    int[] yPoints = {(int)car.getY(),(int)(car.getY()+car.width*sin),(int)(car.getY()+cos*car.length+sin*car.width),
            (int)(car.getY()+car.length*cos)};

    Polygon car = new Polygon(xPoints,yPoints,4);
    int[] recX = {400,450,450,400};
    int[] recY = {400,400,450,450};
    Rectangle2D test = new Rectangle(400,400,100,100);
    ((Graphics2D)g).fill(car);
    ((Graphics2D)g).fill(test);
    if(car.intersects(test)){
        chosenColor = Color.red;
    }
    tk.sync();
}




/**
 * Created by chris on 1/5/16.
 */
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game g = new Game();
}
}



/**
 * Created by chris on 1/5/16.
 * Car class for my driving program.
 */
public class Car {
private double speed;
private double angle;

/**
 * Coordinates on plane
 */
private double x;
private double y;

//For some reason this ends up being the size of the front
public int length = 10;
//and this ends up being the size of the sides.
public int width = 25;


public double getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(double speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

public double getAngle() {
    return angle;
}

public void setAngle(double angle) {
    this.angle = angle;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public Car(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    speed = 0;
    angle = 0;
}

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  2) as an aside, it looks like there might be problems with the paint chain, but it's hard to tell from an uncompilable code snippet.

Comment: What do you mean that there might be problems with the paint chain?

Comment: *"Then I found a solution online that at the beginning of my paint(Graphics g) method, I should place a "super.paintComponent(g)"."* - Ah, no, you should override `paintComponent` and then call `super.paintComponent`, after which you should perform your custom painting. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works.  Also in 17+ years of Swing development, I've never need to use `Toolkit.sync`

Comment: I fixed that. Thank you. Also, I've had problems in other programs than whenever I would take my mouse off the screen, the animation would immediately begin lagging. Someone suggested that after I paint I should call sync(). That fixed the lag problem.

Comment: It's not really appropriate for your `Game` to create a `JFrame` from within it's constructor, instead, you should have a "main" class (with the `main` method), which creates an instance of both and adds the `Game` to the frame there.  You should avoid using `KeyListener`, the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is a better solution

Comment: @user1563074 What OS and Java version causes that problem, never had that issue (with the mouse moving off the screen causing lag)

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and Java 7. Thank you for your help.