# image wont move for scrolling background in java

Tags: java, swing

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;



 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author kids
 */
public class background extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private PaintSurface canvas;
    private BufferedImage image;


    /**
     * Creates new form background
     */
    public background() {
         try {                
          image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\kids\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\game\\src\\backgroundimage.png"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Handle the CLOSE button
        pack();           // pack all the components in the JFrame
        setVisible(true); // show it
        requestFocus();   // set the focus to JFrame to receive KeyEvent

        super.setTitle("Game");
        this.setSize(1056, 540);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(new PaintSurface(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
        canvas = new PaintSurface();
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    class PaintSurface extends JComponent {

        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
int mapWidth = 1056; //Get map width
int mapHeight = 540; //Get map height
int tilesx = 1056/width;
int tilesy = 540/height;
int offsetx = 300;
int offsety = 300;


            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            for(int y=0; y<tilesy; y++)
{
    for(int x=0; x<tilesx; x++)
    {
        g.drawImage(image, x*width-offsetx, y*height-offsety, null);

    }

        }
    }
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(background.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new background();
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

It paints the image, but it does not move when I scroll, so I am confused where the error is. I have looked in various places for an explanation and eventually I tried one.

```
for(int y=0; y<tilesy; y++
{
    for(int x=0; x<tilesx; x++)
    {
        g.drawImage(myimage, x*width, y*height, null);
    }
}
```

This is how he first painted the image, but he later said that in order to make it scroll is simply a matter of adding an offsetx and offsety, where the offset is how much the map is scrolled. I was unsure of how to define these, so I gave them an integer value of 300. The image is now being drawn, but does not respond to scrolling of any kind. I know my code probably makes you gag but very new so please bear with me on this one. Thanks

I believe I followed the steps correctly, but when I came to the last step, using offset i was confused.

Comment: Don't override `paint`, override `paintComponent`, DO call it's `super` method. Why are you adding two instances of `PaintSurface` to the same location of the `JFrame`? How are you expecting it to scroll?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain further? Where is it that I shoudl override paintComponent instead of paint? and how would you suggest making it scroll? Sorry, this is probably all glaringly obvious, but as i previously stated, very new.

Comment: Override paintComponent of paintSurface

Comment: And what would you suggest for the scrolling motion?

Comment: It depends, Swing has a `JScrollPane` or are you planning to implement your own?

Comment: Because im also thinking about having an image on a timer infinitely moving to the right and resetting after it moves off the screen, but i am unsure of how to make that happen as i only know how to when using paint surfaces and canvases.

Comment: Ya.. sorry about being so unclear about my objective..

Comment: Well, [that's one implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048), [that's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419808/frames-painting-at-different-times/25423804#25423804)

Comment: I think i will settle for using a timer and an image to make a game similar to geometry dash except much more basic in the sense that the sprite stays still and the bsckground moves to the side. Im not really sure how to use timers with anything else than graphics though.

Comment: The `Timer` manages the state, the renderer just paints it

Comment: So would i have to assign the image to anything like how one assigns graphics to a canvas? Because when i am creating the timer i also say canvas.repaint. I cant use image.update or image.repaint so is there something i can call instead?